# Convert All XML Attributes to Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, stylesheet

I have a bunch of xml elements formatted like so:

```
<WP featured="yes" player="no" dancers="no" series="logos" archive="no" fanart="no" id="eclipse_logos_">
    <seriesName>LOGOS</seriesName>
    <selection>ECLIPSE</selection>
    <imgurl>http://www.example.com/eclipse_logos_</imgurl>
    <res>1024x1024r(iPad/iPhone)?1280x1024r(Regular)?1440x900r(Widescreen)?1920x1080r(HDTV)?1920x1200r(Widescreen)</res>
</WP>
```

that I want to turn into

```
<WP>
    <featured>yes</featured>
    <player>no</player>
    <dancers>no</dancers>
    <series>logos</series>
    <archive>no</archive>
    <fanart>no></fanart>
    <id>eclipse_logos_</id>
    <seriesName>LOGOS</seriesName>
    <selection>ECLIPSE</selection>
    <imgurl>http://www.example.com/eclipse_logos_</imgurl>
    <res>1024x1024r(iPad/iPhone)?1280x1024r(Regular)?1440x900r(Widescreen)?1920x1080r(HDTV)?1920x1200r(Widescreen)</res>
</WP>
```

after some research, it seems that using an xslt stylesheet is the recommended way to go about this conversion:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am not very familiar with xsl stylesheets. Could someone walk me through the process of applying the transformation? Whenever I try, I get a blank page. I put the following at the top of my xml doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wallpaper.xsl"?>
```

and name the xsl file accordingly. Am I missing something?

Comment: What language do you fancy using? c#, php, ...?

Comment: Take a look at this other answer about using a web browser as your XSLT processor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705845/conversion-of-xml-to-vxml-using-xslt/10714174#10714174

Comment: What is your XSLT engine? Is it browser-based?

Comment: I didn't know I had to have an XSLT engine ^.^ what do you guys recommend?

Comment: I recommend Saxon http://saxon.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You should also change `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">` to `<xsl:template match="node()">` so you don't get ambiguous rule match errors.

Comment: You said "Whenever I try, I get a blank page". So if you tried it, what engine or did you use to try it? What do you mean by "trying it"? How did you "try" it? Down-voting until there is some clarity in your stated objectives.

Comment: I have been using XSelerator for 12 years -- still the best XSLT IDE I have come accross.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want do anything on a computer, you have to find a program that will do it. If you want to apply a stylesheet to an XML document, the program you are looking for is an XSLT processor.

All modern browsers have an XSLT 1.0 processor built-in, and they will invoke it automatically if they see an `<?xml-stylesheet?>` processing instruction in the XML document. But that isn't going to help you much, because all they will do with the output is to display it on the screen, and you presumably want it sent to a file.

There are quite a few XSLT processors around. In nearly all cases they will have a command-line interface. If you're comfortable using the command line on your computer, that's a good way to go. xsltproc and Saxon have been mentioned as possible choices: both are good, but Saxon has the advantage that it supports XSLT 2.0, which you will need sooner or later when you want to do something a bit more complex than this example.

If you aren't comfortable with a command line, there are GUI applications. If you are going to be doing a lot of XML work, it's worth investing in an XML IDE, of which the most popular are Altova XML Spy, Stylus Studio, and oXygen. I use oXygen. If you want something lighter-weight, there's a GUI front-end to Saxon called "Kernow for Saxon" which you can download from SourceForge.

Comment: Sorry if I pitched the response at the wrong level. It's sometimes hard to judge what people know and what they don't.